# Can gaseous hydrogen and gaseous oxygen be compressed without reaction?

Tags: water, gas-laws, hydrogen, pressure

I'm looking into building a clean Bunsen-style burner (or rocket engine - I haven't decided yet). I will be using electrolysis to extract hydrogen and oxygen from water, but the apparatus I am thinking about building will render gaseous hydrogen and gaseous oxygen, but in a mixture. Preferably I would store them compressed, and not have spontaneous combustion.

My question is this:

Will gaseous hydrogen and gaseous oxygen react with each other if compressed in the same chamber?
If so, how much pressure is required before it blows up?

Comment: As far as I know they need a spark to blow. However, such a spark can probably easily be created by electrostatics. I probably wouldn’t risk it if I could avoid it.

Comment: But the pressure alone wouldn't do it?

Comment: When you mix hydrogen and oxygen you have a bomb. Don't do it.

Comment: @MaxW ,so questions involving dangerous experiments are allowed on SE? Shouldn't you stop promoting such questions? Like a flag for "dangerous experiment"? (Just an opinion.)

Comment: @AdityaDev - Not really a problem. After his "experiment," we'll give Daniel a new nickname - "One eyed lefty."

Comment: Nice one. But still. Prevention is better than cure. I don't want someone posting questions like "how to make explosives". We already have terrorist problems :D

Comment: I'm not looking to store a whole lot of it.  Just enough to buffer for the burner.

Comment: You won't make a real rocket from this. Real H2-O2 rockets use liquid gasses and are typically huge.

Comment: Well, I happen to have seen first-hand and tested a working prototype of a rocket engine that burns gaseous H2 and O2.  It was the size of a football (American football that is).  It produced about 10lb of thrust and was quite efficient.

Comment: @MaxW: At least he isn't trying to mix _liquid_ hydrogen with _liquid_ oxygen.

Comment: A demo in college had the prof blowing bubbles with H2 gas and igniting them with a long firestick. Then he mixed some O2 in with the H2, and the pops became louder - and louder - until a bubble about 8 inches in diameter made an unbelievable POP in an auditorium with 300 people. We loved that guy!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The study [Explosion Characteristics of Hydrogen-Air and Hydrogen-Oxygen Mixtures at Elevated Pressures](http://conference.ing.unipi.it/ichs2005/Papers/120001.pdf) includes data for pressures up to 200 bar.

Data were collected for Hydrogen-Oxygen mixtures at both 20 and 80 degrees C at pressures ranging from 1 to 200 bar.  A high voltage spark was still needed to cause explosion.

Storing a compressed mixture of hydrogen and oxygen still seems extremely unsafe to me.  I definitely wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I built something similar to use as oxy /hydrogen welding and cutting. Basically I generated the gasses over water by electrolysis using graphite electrodes and a solar panel. The oxygen and hydrogen were collected separately in tanks made from plastic buckets, in, and separated by, a water bath. The gasses were led out via taps in the bottom of each bucket and only came in contact with each other within a welding handpiece. Pressure was regulated by putting bricks on top of the open bottomed containment tanks and varying the water level above them.
I only ever used pressures up to about 20 psi without any problem.

I wouldn't think that this would be acceptable on a worksite though!!!!

Have fun!